# How to create a list of directory and import images to them

Tags: iphone

As you knew, a iphone app has 4 directories: Application folder, Document, Library, tmp.

When app is installed in the first time, I want to:

1. Create a list of directories in Document folder
2. Import a list of images to each that directories.

I searched and found the way to create directory in Document folder by code.

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:newDirectoryPath attributes: nil];
```

But following that way, user must create folder and import images by themself after installing app. I want my app do that.

Anybody know how to do it, please help me.

Thanks in advance!
Tien

Comment: Hey, maybe it's simple question for you, but it's all my search today.

Comment: Yep. Mark as answer your others questions before asking another please.

Comment: Description of your today's research and the problem you happen to have is very unclear. Consider asking a specific question, describing a problem. It's great that you post code how to create a directory, but we are not interested about what you've already accomplished, but in your problems. What do you mean by saying "user must import images by themself" ? There is no way a user can access those directories.

Comment: Hi, I'm very sorry all for my mistake.

Comment: I will post my problem in more detail later. Thank all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution for my situation. I mean that I want to create a list directory when app run at the first time. But now, I don't need to do it, I just need to add images to my resources folder and find the way to use them in interface builder.

Thanks you all for your attention and sorry for any inconvenient.

Regards,
Tien